# how to know where thread is started

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have a function where i put breakpoint and can see that it is in different thread other than UI thread i mean it is worker thread.i Checked threadwindow for this, when i checked where thread is created and started, i cannot find. Even i checked callstack also.When i drilled i can see only those things starting

```
System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(System.IntPtr userToken) + 0x6c bytes
```

and ends with

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) + 0x74 bytes
```

Do we have any mechanism to find the starting place of thread.My aim is to change the aprtmentmodel of the thread of worker thread

Comment: please show the code where your function is bound to the rest of the system (looks like some async execution, tasks, whatever)

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic i posted code ,else loop part is bounded to rest of the system , my aim is to set STA aprtment for this thread, but for that i need to see where it is created

Comment: Try and find the thread that issued the overlapped read/write call that initiated the IO operation.

Comment: @Martin James do we have any mechanism to find?

Comment: It will probably be waiting in a loop on some 'blahEx' API, SleepEx, WaitForSingleObjectEx, WaitForMultipleObjectsEx, MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx.

Comment: ..and calling WSASend/WSARecv at some point to actually initiate the overlapped IO operations.

Comment: @Martin James okey for the time being is there any mechanism to write exceptions related to thread in to trace file so that UI will be responsive.Due to MTA(i believe) i am getting UI exception and application is stopping.I wrote everywhere tray catch, but not able to cahtch exception, may be something to do in Main method? i will look this problem detail later

Answer (score 6):

Since you are doing some socket operation and the thread apparently started with an IO completion callback, my psychic powers are telling me that this is an IO completion thread. It is informing you that the asynchronous IO operation you started on that socket was completed by the network card.

> My aim is to change the aprtmentmodel of the thread of worker thread

You didn't start that thread; the network socket layer probably did. I wouldn't be trying to change that if I were you.

Comment: Well... IIRC, IO completion callbacks are queued as an APC to a user thread that is normally waiting in an alertable state.  Somewhere, there should be thread that issued the overlapped read/write and then waited on a 'blahEx()' alertable wait call.

Comment: @MartinJames: Your knowledge of this mechanism clearly exceeds mine. Consider posting an answer!

Comment: is there any mechanism to write exceptions related to thread in to trace file so that UI will be responsive.Due to MTA(i believe) i am getting UI exception and application is stopping.I wrote everywhere tray catch, but not able to cahtch exception, may be something to do in Main method? i will look this problem detail later